# Is it possible to get data from excel and use them as watir commands?

Tags: ruby, watir

is it possible to Get data from an excel sheet which are watir commands and execute them.

Comment: In short: yes. Ruby can read from Excel docs pretty easily. However, matters would be somewhat complicated if you were trying to do this in a testing framework, which I'm guessing is the case. If this is for testing, it would be helpful to know what testing tools you are using.

Comment: i did some some research and there are many ways to read and write the excel but how can a data from excel be used as a command , i am running the .rb file from command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string (that you got from excel file) and you want to execute it as code (if I understood what you want to do), you could do something like this:

```
string_from_excel = "goto"
browser.send string_from_excel, "google.com" # the same as browser.goto "google.com"
```

Comment: is it possible that i put that whole command like : -       browser.goto "google.com"                                             in an excel file and it picks up this whole command and executes in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/), it can read Excel files. [Rasta](http://rasta.rubyforge.org/) "is a keyword-driven test framework using spreadsheets to drive testing."